How do the turbopumps in the RS-25 work?
I was looking at a diagram of the RS-25 rocket engine used in the SpaceShuttle program.

You can see two high pressure turbopumps and a fuel and oxidizer pre-burner. I always thought that the turbopumps would run with the help of a gas generator (smaller engine) but I don't see any reference to that, can anyone explain if I'm wrong and where the generator is?

The "smaller engines" are the preburners. These combust part of the propellant in order to drive the turbopumps. The resulting partially combusted gas is then fed through the hot-gas manifold into the main combustion chamber, so that all of the exhaust ultimately leaves by the nozzle.
As described by Wikipedia:

The pre-burners produce the fuel-rich hot gases that pass through the turbines to generate the power needed to operate the high-pressure turbopumps. The oxidizer pre-burner's outflow drives a turbine that is connected to the HPOTP [High-Pressure Oxidizer Turbopump] and to the oxidizer pre-burner pump. The fuel pre-burner's outflow drives a turbine that is connected to the HPFTP [High-Pressure Fuel Turbopump].

The article also includes a more schematized view of the propellant system showing this relationship (turbines in green):

The term "gas generator" is usually associated with a somewhat different design where the exhaust from the preburner is vented directly out of the rocket and don't pass into the combustion chamber at all. This makes for a simpler engine to design and build, but a less efficient one.

Ahhh okay, so when I was referring to "gas generator" I was referring to an open cycle system whereas this is closed cycle?

Btw, are the low pressure fuel turbopumps electric or something else? Also thank you so much for your explaination and the schematic helped a lot!

@Aerospace_Nerd No,they certainly aren't electric or they wouldn't be called turbopumps (that stands for "turbine-driven pump"). As shown in the schematic,their turbines are driven by high-pressure fuel/oxygen diverted from the outlets of the respective high-pressure turbopumps.
